# Potential bug with HTML drag/drop and event bubbling

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop

I noticed that when there's a div inside a div that's handling dragenter/leave events, dragging over the inner div causes the outer div to trigger `dragleave`. But this only happens when the outer div is `position: fixed`. Otherwise, dragging over the child/inner div properly bubbles up to its parent.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ffxsam/L2mvbo2t/

Drag a file over the output pane and you'll see the dropzone show up. If you continue to drag over the "Uh oh" text, the dropzone vanishes. Comment out the `position: fixed` line, then try again, and you'll see if you drag over "Uh oh," the dropzone remains.

Is this a bug? Actually, I just realized that in Firefox, the `dragleave` gets triggered as I move over the inner div, regardless of `position`. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by having three layers:

The full-width `position: fixed` backdrop div, which contains two divs:

- One div with `z-index: 1` that displays text such as "drop here to upload."
- Another div with `z-index: 2` that is full width/height `position: absolute` and sits on top of the previous div to watch for drag events.